# Subtitle support in Hlsjs player

Tags: angular, html, video.js, hls.js

I'm trying to add captions/subtitles to the Hlsjs player that is integrated to my Angular 5 application, and here is the player that I'm using:

https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/

for adding captions I used the 'title' element, and here is how I'm using it:

```
<track crossdomain kind="captions" [src]="selectedClip?.captions" srclang="en" label="English" default>
```

and everything is working fine. But, I the captions I'm receiving are for the entire movie and I would like to add timecode on it so that it has a clear start and end time.

So is there a way to do that using HTML, Hlsjs, or with any other plugin?

Comment: Can you point us to ALL your encoding (e.g. a URL where it is deployed, so we can 'show source' on it?)  I'd then be willing to try to clone it to my webserver and see if I can make it work, as I'm relatively new to angular and always looking for interesting examples. Also, here's one of my (non-angular, non-hls) working pages that does captioning with standard videojs, in case something here might be useful.  https://weasel.firmfriends.us/OnDemand-Sagan/